# C++ list iterator never reaches end() when iterating through

Tags: c++, linux, list, iterator, g++

Ok, I wrote a program which runs perfectly fine when compiled with Visual C++ compiler. Now I want to port it to linux but there is a wierd stuff happening after I compile it in linux.

So, I am trying to loop through a list using an iterator. Here the code:

```
for (list<IntermediateRepresentation>::iterator irIt = funcIt->second.prologue.begin(); irIt != funcIt->second.prologue.end(); ++irIt) {
    irIt->address = address;
    address += getOpcodeSize(irIt->opcode);
}
```

Now the problem is that the above code causes infinite loop. I tried to see why it was doing so in the debugger and I found out that the last element of the list (one that is just before 'end()') was pointing to the 'begin()' iterator instead of 'end()' iterator so when I called '++irIt', it went back to 'begin()'. Is that an expected behaviour?
And another thing I found is that when I do this:

```
size_t irSize = funcIt->second.prologue.size();
```

that causes infinite loop too since it calculates the size using a loop similar to mine. So, it can't be expected behaviour right?

Can anyone give me some hint as where the problem might be?

Oh, and I am using Ubuntu 12.10, g++ version 4.7.2, and eclipse IDE with Linux GCC as toolchain.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not expected behaviour. It looks a bit like memory corruption, could you watch the `end` pointer and traverse step-wise through your program?

Comment: Where do you get `funcIt` from? What is `funcIt->second` for type? What is `funcIt->second.prologue` for type?

Comment: @Charles Bailey 'funcIt' is a an iterator of std::multimap. And it returns by reference perhaps.

Comment: try http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html#debug_mode.using.mode
 `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`

Are you sure that `funcIt` is valid iterator? Does cycle iterating valid values while in infinite loop?

Comment: 'funcIt' is a an iterator of std::multimap. funcIt->second is a struct, and prologue is a member of that struct which is a std::list<IntermediateRepresentation>. And IntermediateRepresentation is again a struct.

Comment: `funcIt->second.prologue` doesn't get modified during your loop, does it? Although that wouldn't explain the `size()`-issue.

Comment: Besides, why are you ++irIt?

Comment: funcIt looks like a valid iterator to me when I debug. The loop is doing what it is suppose to do, but doing it infinitely. When it reaches the last item in list, it goes back to first item without reaching 'end()'.

Comment: @bash.d What else would he do?

Comment: Run it with `valgrind` and see if that catches anything, otherwise you will have to debug build the STL.

Comment: The std::list is a doubly linked list. Could you by any chance have it configured like so: `last->next = first`?

Comment: @scai The value in funcIt->second.prologue.address gets modified during the loop.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain he is preincrementing, possibly skipping a value, so irIt++ seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Roman Saveljev Do you mean in code? I don't think I have done that anywhere but I will check.

Comment: What does `getOpcodeSize` do? Could it modify the list in any way?

Comment: @bash.d It is idiomatic (and more correct) to preincrement.

Comment: @Peter Wood The getOpcodeSize take a short int as a parameter (by value) and returns the size of a opcode. So, nah it cannot actually modify the list.

Comment: Could splicing a list to another list could have generated such problem? 'Cause I have used splice in number of places like this: list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yes, the program is single threaded.

Comment: @PradipnaNepal Yes, that's likely to be it.

Comment: @PeterWood So, what is the right way to splice?

Comment: @PradipnaNepal What have you tried? (c:

Comment: @PradipnaNepal http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice
there is undefined behavior if you are splicing part of list inside that part of list %)

Comment: @PeterWood and kassak, Thank you both. I found and fixed the problem. I was splicing a list with itself due to some bug. Thank you both for pointing me to right direction. And thank you all who replied to my thread. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have likely created an invalid [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) by splicing in into itself.

For example, usage of the third variation of [splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice):

```
void splice(const_iterator pos, list& other, 
            const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

> 3) Moves the elements in the range `[first, last)` from `other` into `*this`. The elements are inserted before the element pointed to by `pos`. The behavior is undefined if `pos` is an iterator in the range `[first,last)`.